# How to configure zsh under Windows to complete foo.exe as foo, for any foo?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

Is there some simple way to configure zsh to use the same completer for `foo.exe` as for `foo` itself for any foo? By default this doesn't seem to happen, and so pressing TAB after `git.exe` uses the default file completion instead of Git-specific command completion, as when pressing TAB after `git`. I realize I could change this using `compdef` specifically for git, but is it possible to do it for all commands at once?

Comment: Since you are on Windows: At least in the Cygwin implementation of zsh, this completion is already builtin. What zsh are you using? Are you sure that you have `foo.exe` in your path? Do a `type -a foo.exe` to verify this.

Comment: I do use zsh from Cygwin and it's not a question of the path, even specifying full path to the command doesn't help -- for me, completing `c:\full\path\to\git.exe` completes file names instead of Git commands. If it is already built-in, at which level is this done, is this a Cygwin or zsh thing?

Comment: Path separator is /, not  \ . Completion is done in zsh, but I guess that when porting zsh to Cygwin, they have to adapt some pieces for the Windows environment.  Try a `type -a cmd`. On my platform, I get as response _cmd is /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/cmd_.

Comment: Yes, sure, I used backslashes for clarity, but the real path is `/cygdrive/c/whatever/git.exe`. And completion works for `/cygdrive/c/whatever/git`, but not for the one with the `.exe` suffix.

Comment: Did you try it with `cmd` as I suggested? In Cygwin (if you look at the executables in you Cygwin /bin directory using Windows explorer), all binaries there have an .exe suffix, but Cygwin is hiding it.  When I type `cmd` and then 2 tab characters, I get as list _cmd  cmd.exe  cmdext.dll  cmdial32.dll  cmdkey  cmdkey.exe  cmdl32  cmdl32.exe_, where _cmd_  and _cmd.exe_  denote the identical file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what is your point. I'm not asking about completing `foo` itself to `foo.exe`, I'm asking about the completion used for `foo.exe` if it already happens to be present on the command line (due to being copy-pasted there, being the result of an alias expansion, whatever). This has nothing to do with `type -a foo` AFAICS.

Comment: I think i don't understand your question then. So you typed on the command line `foo.exe` and then hit the _tab_ key. What expansion would you like to see?

Comment: When I type `git ` (note the space), `TAB` completes Git commands. When I type `git.exe `, it completes file names (default completion). I'd like the latter work like the former but not only for Git (I know how to do this), but for all commands.

Comment: Now your requirement becomes clear to me. I found the mentioning of _for **any** foo_ in your question confusing, because `foo` and `foo.exe` are the same, and you basically want to accomplish completion just for _foo_, in a similar way as it is done for _git_. Sadly, I've never specified a new completion command, so I can not help you here. However, in order to find help, I suggest that you also provide the _compdef_ statements you tried (even if they don't work), and that you specify exactly what you hope to see when you press the _tab_ key after `foo`.